# How do I embed NoSQL database to my browser for offline experience?

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, offline-mode, nosql

I want to have a document oriented database with features like find, insert, modify and other found in MongoDB, to be be available to my browser ( Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android is good enough, actually ). We do have SQLLite but it is relational. I am ok to get even a wrapper on top of any existing storage mechanism as long as the typical operations are supported.

I have gone through :

- http://zef.me/2774/persistence-js-an-asynchronous-javascript-orm-for-html5gears
- https://github.com/michael/data

But these are not as closed to what I am looking for. I just wonder if there are better solutions solution available ?

Comment: @Samayak, i believe [persistence .js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) is got all the ingredients you are looking for.. Can you please be specific what is exactly your requirement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [TaffyDB](http://taffydb.com/). Its a javasript implementation of database leveraging the associative arrays (JSON objects). So ultimately you get the document oriented database.

Also it provides nice set of functions to manipulate the data as you expected .

But as per my knowledge it **doesn't have the offline storage**. But i believe its possible to implement the local storage with the HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: TaffyDB indeed supports offline storage using `db.store()`. See http://taffydb.com/#data. I find the TaffyDB close to what I was looking for. Need to do some performance benchmarks now.